# Closed sets in a subspace are formed by intersecting the subspace with closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $Y$ be a subset of $X$ be a subspace with the induced metric. (induced means the metric restricted to elements of $Y$) Let $A$ be a subset of $Y$. Prove the following facts.

If $A$ is closed in $Y$ then there exist a set $B$ closed in $X$ such that $A=B\cap Y$

The reciprocal. If $A = B\cap  Y$ for some closed set $B$ on $X$, then $A$ is closed in $Y$.

The first proof is as follows:

Let $B$ be the closure of $A$ on $X$, which is closed in $X$. This closed set of $X$ intersected with $Y$ will give us $A$.

The second part is a little trickier, I don't really know how to go about it.

Comment: How about showing that $Y \setminus A$ is open in $Y$?

Comment: Actually, by definition of the induced topology, the open (closed) subsets of the subspace Y of a topological space X are exactly the traces on Y of all open (resp. closed) subsets of X.

Comment: @ Jade NB. what is meant by 'Y\A' I've never seen such notation

Comment: @Seedof: $Y \setminus A = \{y \in Y \mid y \not \in A\}$.

Comment: @PietroMajer I think the question is to show the induced metric space topology is equivalent to the topology induced by the restricted metric.

Answer (score 1):

Since $B$ is closed in $X$, then $B\cap Y$ contains all its limits in $Y$ so is closed in $Y$